# Reading list from Restful API

Tags: java, angular, rest, arraylist, crud

(First time asking a question here) I created a rest api on java that returns all the cars available in the table Cars from my db. I found a way to get one of the cars with an specific Id and can show it on my page, but it can't understand how to show all the cars in the same page. Basically i don't understand how to show the arraylist that I get from my Rest Api and show it. I see the whole array in the console but not on my html. I not asking for the whole architecture of angular, just want to know how to show on my app-component when I click a button all the items that my rest has.

My rest:

```
@GET
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    public List<CarDto> getCars() {
        Car macchina;
        // CarDao trasform1 = new CarDao();
        CarDto trasform2;
        // java 8+ lambda function, Stream (per divertimento)
        List<Car> listaMac = carDao.getCars();
        List<CarDto> listaMacAgg = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listaMac.size(); i++) {
            trasform2 = new CarDto(listaMac.get(i));
            listaMacAgg.add(trasform2);
        }
        return listaMacAgg;
    }
```

The class from my app component that gets the response from my rest:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'rest agency test';
  caid: string = "";
  response: any;
  response2:any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  ngOnInit(){
  }

  search(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/rest_agency/rest/hello/'+this.caid)
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.response = response;
      console.log(this.response);
    })
  }
  allCars(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/rest_agency/rest/hello')
    .subscribe((response2) => {
      this.response = response2;
      console.log(this.response);
    })
  }




}
```

my app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <p><button (click)="allCars()"> All Cars</button></p>
  <p>Search id:<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="caid">
    <button (click)="search()">Search</button></p>
  <div *ngIf="response2">
    <table>
     <ul class="heroes">
       <tr>
           <td>ID</td>
           <td>Brand</td>
           <td>Color</td>
           <td>Year</td>
           <td>Price</td>
           <td>Sold</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <div *ngFor="let all of response | keyvalue">
             <td><li>{{response.caId}}</li></td>
             <td><li>{{response?.brand}}</li></td>
             <td><li>{{response?.color}}</li></td>
             <td><li>{{response?.year}}</li></td>
             <td><li>{{response?.price}}</li></td>
             <td><li>{{response?.sold}}</li></td>
           </div>
         </tr>
       </ul>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="response"> {{response.caid}}
      <table>
        <ul class="heroes">
          <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Brand</td>
            <td>Color</td>
            <td>Year</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Sold</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><li>{{response?.caId}}</li></td>
              <td><li>{{response?.brand}}</li></td>
              <td><li>{{response?.color}}</li></td>
              <td><li>{{response?.year}}</li></td>
              <td><li>{{response?.price}}</li></td>
              <td><li>{{response?.sold}}</li></td>
          </tr>
        </ul>
      </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

I was expecting the result of all the info of the arraylist that comes from the rest

here is what it shows calling one id : https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgC7S.jpg
and here's what happens when call the whole list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiZzF.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say `<div *ngIf="response2">` but you never store anything in response2. As a result this block is never shown. Please change to

```
allCars(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/rest_agency/rest/hello')
    .subscribe((response2) => {
      this.response2 = response2;
      console.log(this.response);
    })
  }
```

--

```
<div *ngIf="response2">
    <table>
     <ul class="heroes">
       <tr>
           <td>ID</td>
           <td>Brand</td>
           <td>Color</td>
           <td>Year</td>
           <td>Price</td>
           <td>Sold</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <div *ngFor="let all of response2 | keyvalue">
             <td><li>{{all.caId}}</li></td>
             <td><li>{{all.brand}}</li></td>
             <td><li>{{all.color}}</li></td>
             <td><li>{{all.year}}</li></td>
             <td><li>{{all.price}}</li></td>
             <td><li>{{all.sold}}</li></td>
           </div>
         </tr>
       </ul>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Is the keyvalue really necesary? I highly recommend to type your stuff, avoid any

PS.: Your Lamba function likely looks like this (much shorter)

```
@GET
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public List<CarDto> getCars() {
    return carDao.getCars().stream().map(car => new CarDto(car)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Can you please upvote the answer and mark is as solution? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is **error**

```
 <div *ngFor="let all of response2 | keyvalue">
```

change to

```
<div *ngIf="response">
    <table>
     <ul class="heroes">
       <tr>
           <td>ID</td>
           <td>Brand</td>
           <td>Color</td>
           <td>Year</td>
           <td>Price</td>
           <td>Sold</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <div *ngFor="let respone_one of response | keyvalue">
             <td><li>{{respone_one?.caId}}</li></td>
             <td><li>{{respone_one?.brand}}</li></td>
             <td><li>{{respone_one?.color}}</li></td>
             <td><li>{{respone_one?.year}}</li></td>
             <td><li>{{respone_one?.price}}</li></td>
             <td><li>{{respone_one?.sold}}</li></td>
           </div>
         </tr>
       </ul>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: When I use the "response", it creates two lines of the whole id/brand/color etc, but doesn't show anything else. I think that my first error is that i'm calling the response2?.field ref instead of the all reference. But it didn't work either :(.

This happens because i'm also using response for the search_by_id. That's why i created a second response (response2) to use it on the page.

Comment: can you add screen shot and i will check it

Comment: Calling by id: https://imgur.com/I49wY3h
calling all cars: https://imgur.com/EwsBRRu

Comment: copy response data and send to me  or edit question with it

Comment: found the anwser by using MoxxiManagarm & Anton Bks suggestions (which were similar to yours by making me find out that i was calling the wrong reference) :). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes from the ngFor `let all of response | keyvalue`. The values you are looking for are in the `all` reference, not `response`.

Try this:

```
      <div *ngFor="let all of response | keyvalue">
         <td><li>{{all?.caId}}</li></td>
         <td><li>{{all?.brand}}</li></td>
         <td><li>{{all?.color}}</li></td>
         <td><li>{{all?.year}}</li></td>
         <td><li>{{all?.price}}</li></td>
         <td><li>{{all?.sold}}</li></td>
       </div>
```

Comment: I thought it could work since you are right, i need to call the all reference, but it didn't work :(. I still get all the arraylist on the console (example: https://imgur.com/pdjg4aq) :(

Comment: The console output will not change since you are logging `console.log(this.response);` and not the reference to the object in the loop. You could check for the correct reference like so:  `<div *ngFor="let all of response | keyvalue">{{all}}</div>` this will render the object one by one on your page.

Comment: Thanks. It worked with you help and MoxxiManagarm help :). Orbit had the same idea as you, cause Orbit saw my huge mistake calling response instead of all reference

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Good luck!